# Firefox 25 new error messages appear

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

Since I updated to Firefox 25 some additional error messages appear.

The biggest problem was, that I had to set 'javascript.options.strict': False in the addon-sdk-1.14/python-lib/cuddlefish/prefs.py to get rid of all the error messages coming from pages I open in Firefox that had nothing to do with my addon. Bad but necessary.

Now there is one more message, that don't care about javascript.options.strict.

First think, it again complains about problems, that are not part of my addon.
Second: How can I suppress this message?

```
Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: http://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdn43/33f95befb79bddddf0343f545d067d.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
```

Comment: Unless you can edit the JavaScript file directly, you can't remove the message. In either case, it doesn't affect the running of your code, so you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I'd alert the 'owner' of the code that throws the error . . .

Comment: It's jQuery 1.9.1 used in that page ^^.
You are right, I'm able to ignore it, but it's damn hard, cause it appears on any page load and I see it between my own messages, that I use during development.

Comment: Where are you seeing the logs? If you're using the Browser Console, you can filter messages seen under the JS category to only show errors.

Comment: I see it in the command line from where I start Firefox during addon development